# MySQL Stored Procedure errors with ERROR 1064 (42000) line 1?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've looked through similar questions, but none seemed to help me fix the error I am getting.

Here is the procedure I am trying to create:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE replaceFieldTextTo (IN v_string_from VARCHAR(255), IN v_string_to VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE table_name_value VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE column_name_value VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE cursor_fields CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'field_%_value';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cursor_fields;

  ColumnList: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_fields INTO table_name_value, column_name_value;

    IF done THEN 
      Leave ColumnList;
    END IF;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE ', table_name_value, ' SET ', column_name_value, ' = replace(', column_name_value, ', "', v_string_from, '", "', v_string_to ,'"');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cursor_fields;
END;
```

The statement itself is created just fine. But calling it results in an error.

Basically I want to find and replace text across numerous tables, but I get:

```
mysql> CALL replaceFieldTextTo("http://dev.mywebsite.org","/");
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I am not really seeing the issue. I am prefacing this with `delimiter //` in the mysql console, and `delimiter ;` afterward.

Comment: Close parenthesis. `... UPDATE ... "', v_string_to ,'")');`.

Comment: THAT was it! Thanks a lot! Post as the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Just as a side thought, you might want to have information_schema call check to see if you're replacing a VARCHAR.

Comment: Some are, some are LONGTEXT... how can I check?